# Hacer relación de dos tablas por cantidades iguales

Tags: sql-server

[image: Resultado Query]

Quisiera unir estas dos tablas y saber que GRN pertenece a cada PKItem, dependiendo de la cantidad, si alguien me puede ayudar, estoy un poco perdido, gracias

Comment: No veo relación alguna, por ejemplo si la sumatoria de cantidades podría coincidir en mas de un escenario

Comment: La relación está en que las cantidad del GRN debe ser igual a la cantidad de un PKItem QtyReceiving

Comment: Es decir 1 a 1,  si tabla 1. Quantity es 1300 directamente va contra tabla 2 QtyReceiving de 1300 ...

Comment: De ser asi, en e ejemplo que pasaste, ninguno coincidiría.

Comment: Por ejemplo, El PKItem 57257, su cantidad es 1300, ahora esa cantidad debo saber a que GRN pertenece, por ejemplo El GRN 1073213768 cantidad 500, 1073213773 cantidad 500, 1073213914 cantidad 100 y 1073213918 cantidad 200, la suma total de esos GRNS es 1300, que es la cantidad del PKItem 57257.

Comment: Es imposible saber exactamente cual GRN pertenece a cual PKItem ya que tienes muchísimas combinaciones posibles para que pueda darte la cantidad deseada, por lo que te puede dar diferentes resultados.

Comment: Lo que dice Victor es correcto, no puedes relacionar por monto, vas a obtener datos totalmente falsos, más con esas cantidades tan cerradas.